# ansible- expect module with cisco ios switch

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

If I try to use expect module in YAML file like this:

```
   name: some tests
      hosts: sw-test
      gather_facts: False

      tasks:
      - name: do reload in case of "catting off"
        expect:
         command: reload in 30
         responses:
          'Reload scheduled in 30 minutes by admin on vty0 (192.168.253.20)\nProceed with reload? \[confirm\]' : y
         echo: yes
```

But there is a problem with connection:

```
root@Kali:/etc/ansible# ansible-playbook test3 -u admin -k -vvvv 
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password: 
Loaded callback default of type stdout, v2.0

PLAYBOOK: test3 ****************************************************************
1 plays in test3

PLAY [some tests] **************************************************************

TASK [do reload in case of "catting off"] **************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/test3:9
<192.168.0.33> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<192.168.0.33> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=admin -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 192.168.0.33 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882070.37-92402455055985 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1476882070.37-92402455055985="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882070.37-92402455055985 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.0.33> PUT /tmp/tmp30wGsF TO "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882070.37-92402455055985 `" ) && sleep 0'"/expect
<192.168.0.33> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=admin -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[192.168.0.33]'
fatal: [192.168.0.33]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to the remote host. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable": true}
    to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/test3.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.0.33               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   


root@Kali:/etc/ansible# ansible-playbook test3 -u admin -k -vvvv -c ssh
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password: 
Loaded callback default of type stdout, v2.0

PLAYBOOK: test3 ****************************************************************
1 plays in test3

PLAY [some tests] **************************************************************

TASK [do reload in case of "catting off"] **************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/test3:9
<192.168.0.33> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: admin
<192.168.0.33> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=admin -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r 192.168.0.33 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882145.78-139203779538157 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1476882145.78-139203779538157="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882145.78-139203779538157 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<192.168.0.33> PUT /tmp/tmpY5qqyW TO "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882145.78-139203779538157 `" ) && sleep 0'"/expect
<192.168.0.33> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d12 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -C -vvv -o 

ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o User=admin -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r '[192.168.0.33]'
    fatal: [192.168.0.33]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to the remote host. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable": true}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/test3.retry

    PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
    192.168.0.33               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0   

root@Kali:/etc/ansible# ansible-playbook test3 -u admin -k -vvvv -c local
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
SSH password: 
Loaded callback default of type stdout, v2.0

PLAYBOOK: test3 ****************************************************************
1 plays in test3

PLAY [some tests] **************************************************************

TASK [do reload in case of "catting off"] **************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/test3:9
<192.168.0.33> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<192.168.0.33> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882426.62-172601217553809 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1476882426.62-172601217553809="` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882426.62-172601217553809 `" ) && sleep 0'
<192.168.0.33> PUT /tmp/tmpdq1pYy TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882426.62-172601217553809/expect
<192.168.0.33> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882426.62-172601217553809/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882426.62-172601217553809/expect && sleep 0'
<192.168.0.33> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8 LC_ALL=pl_PL.UTF-8 LC_MESSAGES=pl_PL.UTF-8 /usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882426.62-172601217553809/expect; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1476882426.62-172601217553809/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [192.168.0.33]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"chdir": null, "command": "reload in 30", "creates": null, "echo": true, "removes": null, "responses": {"Reload scheduled in 30 minutes by admin on vty0 (192.168.253.20)\\nProceed with reload? \\[confirm\\]": "y"}, "timeout": 30}, "module_name": "expect"}, "msg": "The command was not found or was not executable: reload."}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
    to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/test3.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.0.33               : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Is it possible to use expect module with cisco ios switch?
I have no such problem when I use for instance "ios_command" module.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you are out of luck here, because for [expect](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html) module you need:

> Requirements (on host that executes module)
> python >= 2.6
> pexpect >= 3.3

And there are hardly any python and pexpect present on your IOS switch.

Comment: Which means that this is immposible to use thos module with cisco IOS?

Comment: Yes. Generally you need python installed on target box for ordinary modules to work. There are few exceptions, like `raw`, for example. Also there are modules for specific hardware, like `ios_command` which use tools available on the device and don't require additional libraries.

Comment: Above question was born becouse i tried to handle some cisco command that needs to be confirmd before prompt is shown again. And I was adviced to try using expect module. Mayby you can look and try answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045342/ansible-cisco-ios-and-reload-command . Thanks in advance.