# how to handle multiple prompts in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am copying the startup-config file to cisco router and trying to reload the cisco router C2900 using Ansible.
Tried using ios_command module and cli_command module with 'prompt and answer' but still no luck.
my playbooks for reload looks like

using ios_command module:

```
- name: reload one device
  ios_command:
    commands:
      - command: 'reload in 0:01'
        prompt: 'System configuration has been modified. Save? [yes/no]'
        answer: 'y'
        prompt: 'Proceed with reload? [confirm]'
        answer: 'y'
```

using cli_command:

```
- name: reload one device
  cli_command:
    commands:
      - command: 'reload in 0:01'
        prompt: 
          - 'System configuration has been modified. Save? [yes/no]'
          - 'Proceed with reload? [confirm]'
        answer: 
          - 'y'
          - 'y'
```

Both are not working. It does not throwing any error as well.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: also tried all solutions from this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40045342/ansible-cisco-ios-and-reload-command?rq=1 but not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 vars_prompt:
       - name: var1
         private: no
         prompt: "what is var1"
       - name: var2
         private: no
         prompt: "what is var2"
       - name: var3
         private: no
         prompt: "var3"
```

Use the ios_config module with the vars from the prompt.. '{{ var1 }}', '{{ var2 }}'

if you are responding to a prompt on the console, you could try using psexpect